# userData is undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

### Hi everyone,

I'm trying to add a name to my 3DObject in order to print their name later.
So, the click on the Object works well, the Outline works too... but the userData field is still empty.

Here is my code :

```
function checkIfClicked(event) {
        mouse.x = (event.offsetX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - (event.offsetY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([model], true);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            click_level += 1;

            selectedObject = intersects[0].object;
            console.log(selectedObject.userData.name); //Here is the problem
            outlinePass.selectedObjects = [selectedObject];
            if (click_level > 1) {
                if (confirm("You are going to be redirected to Zalando.be")) {
                    document.location.href = "http://www.zalando.be";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            click_level = 0;
            outlinePass.selectedObjects = [];
        }
}
```

And in my main code, once the 3DObject is loaded :

```
object.userData = { name: "homme" };
model = object;
console.log(model.userData); //Works here
```

#### Is there something i do wrong ?

Comment: Does your model have child objects?  I wonder if because you have selected recursion in the intersectObjects function that a child object is selected, and that you only added the name property to the parent.  Just a thought.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it not like an object:

```js
var object = new THREE.Object3D();
object.userData.name = "name1";
document.body.innerHTML = object.userData.name;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! Itried this, but it is still undefined when i try to print it in my checkIfClicked function...

Comment: @GuillaumeDeniau Is there any chance to see your live code? A link, for example.